# How to avoid double quotes for is equal to when using segment builder

Tags: content-search, segmentation

I'm creating a condition for the segment builder inheriting from `TypedQueryableStringOperatorCondition`.

I'm overriding the method `GetResultPredicate` to apply my filter like this

```
return base.GetCompareExpression((IndexedContact c) => c["contact.myfield"], "myvalue");
```

This is translated into the following query:

> contact.myfield:myvalue

So good so far, but if the value I'm looking for has more than one word or pipe to split terms it adds double quotes to the query:

```
return base.GetCompareExpression((IndexedContact c) => c["contact.myfield"], "my value");
```

This is translated into the following query:

> contact.myfield:"my value"

In my case the query I'm trying to get is:

> contact.myfield:my value

To get result containing "my" or "value"
I have tried using the Operator contains, but it has been translated into a massive `spanNear([SpanWildcardQuery`.

Any idea how to achieve the query:

> contact.myfield:my value

Trying to make it easier or clearer what I'm really trying to do is to find contacts containing any of the "words" in that field. It's fine If I have to change the approach.

Comment: What's wrong with `contact.myfield:"my value"`? To me it looks like the more correct syntax.

Comment: I'm trying to find any of the 2 terms, with the double quotes it becomes one single term. As my index field is tokenized, it doesn't find. If i don't save it tokenized and I store "my red value" as a single term, It wouldn't find "my value" neither. As I mentioned before I tried the "contains", but it didn't work neither

Comment: What is the condition that you have set in the rule for this action?

Comment: It's a custom condition.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the comparison operator - like `Equals` etc....

Comment: "Is equal to": {10537C58-1684-4CAB-B4C0-40C10907CE31}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an "or"-based expression that has a separate condition for every search term:

```
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Utilities;

// ...

IEnumerable<string> keywords = new string[] { "my", "value" };

Expression<Func<IndexedContact, bool>> keywordsPredicate =
    keywords.Aggregate(
        PredicateBuilder.False<IndexedContact>(),
            (current, keyword) => current.Or(
                c => base.GetCompareExpression(c["contact.myfield"], keyword)));

return keywordsPredicate;
```

Please note that `GetCompareExpression()` may return different operators. It's up to you what to do when the operator is not "equals".

Comment: I think the problem is that the operator here is set by the rules engine, not hard coded. The `GetResultPredicate` ultimately works off the selected `StringConditionOperator` to work out what the operator is.

Comment: @RichardSeal Thanks, I updated the answer to get the operator properly.

Comment: I'm not allowing users to select the operator as this is my logic and requirement I'm hard coding it. Using the predicate builder did the trick, thanks.